# Which industry has more interesting use cases and more room to learn for Data Scientist, between Retail and Banking?

Tags: careers

I am posing this question here due to the active community of Data Scientist and people with real industry experience here. I did not put in career advice because this is where we have real people with industry experience. Admin please advises as you see fit.

Let's say I have offers from both a major Retail company (conglomerate type of Walmart scale) and a major Bank as a Data Scientist (possibly IBM as a Data Scientist consultant as well).

I'd like to have advices from Data Scientist from different domains, regarding which industry do you feel has more room to learn, interesting subjects, use cases, technology stacks, etc. ? This is my first serious Data Scientist job so I would like to choose carefully.

Thank you.

Comment: Probably off-topic, but I think it depends more on what the job responsibilities are than the industry itself.

Comment: The job responsibilities are very similar for data scientists if you look at it. It boils down to the diversity of topics that exist in that industry, potentials or technology stacks. For example in pharma world a major topic would be clinical trial, an HR consulting company would revolve around parsing resumes and job posts. That's why I am seeking advices from those who have been through. My previous boss said Retail and Banking are most exciting. Retail use-cases: analyze ticket, client shopping habit, marketing, promotion campaign, store layout, logistics, optimized storage, product design

Comment: This question would probably be more on topic at datascience.stackexchange.com, although marginal even there.